# How to pass arguments between functions

Tags: functions

I have two Functions, `f[]` and `g[]`. `f` is passed some values ,say `{w,x,y,z}`  and I want to send one of those to `g` say `x`. I don't want this operation to interfere with other operations.

Comment: can you be more specific? eg why does `g[x_]:=x; f[{w_,x_,y_,z_}]:=g[x]` not work?

Comment: `f[l_]:=(g[First@l]; whatever)`

Comment: @acl fine i'l tell you the entire problem.

Comment: you don't need to put the entire problem here, just some sort of minimal example

Comment: i have f[{w_,x_,y_,z_}]:= "Some Definition.." and g[{a_,b_,c_}]:= "some definition" . i cant use your solution in this case. g[] already has a different definition. How do i pass "x" to a variable in g[] in this case.?

Comment: The better you explain your problem to us, the better the chances to get good answers. Your question style so far is kind of short bordering on incomplete.

Comment: could you explain better what it is you're trying to do? You want to pass `x` to `g`, why can't you just do `g[{a,x,c}]` or whatever?

Comment: Why don't you give us an example? Or maybe try to write things down like you would do in paper, but not in code?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you have in mind by any chance?
I'm simply using an external variable to store the `x` passed to `f` when `f` is called.
The `Module` is there so that that external variable is only known by `f` and `g` and you don't accidentally use it in other places

```
Module[{var},
 f[{w_, x_, y_, z_}] := (var = x; 8);
 g[] := var
 ]
```

So now if you run

```
f[{1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

you get

```
(* 8 *)
```

But next time you run `g[]` you get the "x argument" passed to `f` the last time it was called

```
g[]

(* 2 *)
```